# Header bar with <p:sticky tag/> and datatable header bar <p:datatable stickyHeader = "true"/> duplicate each other

Tags: primefaces

In Primeface, datatable have sticky header.The one i need to do is that I want one header bar and one datatable header bar not duplicating each other.Is there a way to do that?I want them one after another like that.

==========================

## Header Bar

==========================

## Datatable Header Bar

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide some source code that reproduces your issue? See [mcve]

Comment: And please, please, please, post version info. For all we know you use a 6.0 version where something like this was a problem....

Comment: sry for my request.Version is 6.0.I have researched and now the only thing i want to know is that can i set margin value to primeface datatable sticky header.If can, how?Thz for all of your answers.